# How to Stop a Toggle Button from being deactivated by a click

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

I have 4 `ToggleButton`s set up in an `OnCheckedChangeListener()`.

`ToggleButton` 1 is activated on startup and the listener is set so that when you press another `ToggleButton` within the checker, it deactivates the first button and then activates the button that you clicked.

However, when I click a `ToggleButton` that is already activated, it deactivates itself which is not what I want.

I want to know, is there a way of doing this so that an activated `ToggleButton` can only be deactivated by pressing one of the other `ToggleButton`s with the checker?

This Is what I have But It Doesn't seem to work.

```
 OnCheckedChangeListener toggleChangeChecker = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (isChecked){
                if (buttonView == one) {
                    one.setChecked(true);
                    two.setChecked(false);
                    three.setChecked(false);
                    four.setChecked(false);
                }
                if (buttonView == two) {
                    one.setChecked(false);
                    two.setChecked(true);
                    three.setChecked(false);
                    four.setChecked(false);
                }
                if (buttonView == three) {
                    one.setChecked(false);
                    two.setChecked(false);
                    three.setChecked(true);
                    four.setChecked(false);
                }
                if (buttonView == four) {
                    one.setChecked(false);
                    two.setChecked(false);
                    three.setChecked(false);
                    four.setChecked(true);
                }

            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: You already set up the `OnCheckedChangeListener`. You just need to add some logic there which prevents a checked `ToogleButton` from becoming unchecked.

Comment: Any ideas on how you would do it. I need 1 of the ToggleButtons to be checked all the time while only being unchecked by clicking one of the other ToggleButtons

Comment: It really isn't that difficult. Just save which one is currently checked and in the `OnCheckedChangeListener` just check if the that's the one which is currently being unchecked. If yes then check it again.

Comment: Check the code. Can you see what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `if(yourButton.isChecked()) yourButton.setChecked(true);` inside your OnCheckedChangeListener, guess that would do the trick.

Comment: I tried putting this in OnCheckedChangeListener but it didn't work any other ideas

Comment: try to add this in a second if(!isChecked) condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isChecked) { button.setEnabled(false); }
else { button.setEnabled(true); }
```

Comment: `button.setEnabled(!isChecked);`

Comment: It is good practice to include a description of your answer rather than simply submitting code. A good answer is clear and concise, with all/any code being well described so that the asker understands it.